# Php logic to add to date card

Tags: php

This is the output I want:

For example, today is Monday 20th - the Thursday the 23rd, so the next available date will be Tuesday the 4th.
So my output should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="colour-button1" value="10 - 12" id="btn1" disabled/><label for="btn1" style="position:relative;"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg hide11" id="chk-btn1"></i>   Tuesday, March 28</label>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="colour-button1" value="10 - 12" id="btn2" disabled /><label for="btn2" class="labe1" style="position:relative;"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg hide11" id="chk-btn2"></i>  Thursday,March 30th</label>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="colour-button1" value="10 - 12" id="btn3" disabled/><label for="btn3" style="position:relative;"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg hide11" id="chk-btn3"></i>  Tuesday, April 4th</label>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="colour-button1" value="10 - 12" id="btn4" disabled/><label for="btn4" class="labe1" style="position:relative;"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg hide11" id="chk-btn4"></i>  Thursday, April 6th</label>
```

If it is Friday the 24th- Sunday the 26th, the next available date is Tuesday April 4th

```
<input type="checkbox" class="colour-button1" value="10 - 12" id="btn1" disabled/><label for="btn1" style="position:relative;"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg hide11" id="chk-btn1"></i>   Tuesday, April 4th</label>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="colour-button1" value="10 - 12" id="btn2" disabled /><label for="btn2" class="labe1" style="position:relative;"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg hide11" id="chk-btn2"></i>  Thursday, April 6th</label>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="colour-button1" value="10 - 12" id="btn3" disabled/><label for="btn3" style="position:relative;"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg hide11" id="chk-btn3"></i>  Tuesday, April 11th</label>
<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" class="colour-button1" value="10 - 12" id="btn4" disabled/><label for="btn4" class="labe1" style="position:relative;"><i class="fa fa-check-circle fa-lg hide11" id="chk-btn4"></i>  Thursday, April 13th</label>
```

I tried this, before I could implement it on my form but all I got was "Monday March 27th"

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo '<pre>';


// DAY NAMES TO WEEK INTERVALS
$weekdays = array
(         'Mon' => ' + 1 week'
        , 'Tue' => ' + 6 days'
        , 'Wed' => ' + 5 days'
        , 'Thu' => ' + 4 days'
        , 'Fri' => ' + 10 days'
        , 'Sat' => ' + 11 days'
        , 'Sun' => ' + 12 days'
)
;

// CREATE A RANGE OF ISO DATES FOR THIS WEEK
$anchor_day = 'last Monday';
if (date('D') == 'Mon') $anchor_day = 'Today';
$anchor = date('l, F dS', strtotime($anchor_day));
for( $i = 0; $i<4; $i++ )
{
    $time = strtotime("$anchor + $i days");
    $day  = date('D', $time);
    $days[$day] = date('l, F dS', strtotime("$anchor + $i days"));
}


// CREATE THE FUTURE DATES BY COMBINING ISO DAYS AND WEEKDAY RULES
foreach($days as $day => $iso)
{
    $new = date('l, F dS', strtotime($iso . $weekdays[$day]));
    echo PHP_EOL . "$day: $new";
}


?>
```

Comment: I do not know who gave you a positive vote but they are out of their mind. I read the whole thing at least 5 times and it makes no sense whatsoever. If it is 20th to 23rd next available date is 4th. On the other hand if it is between 24th and 26 the next available date is AGAIN 4th. Can you try and see yourself from our point of view reading it and see that it makes no sense.